# XML属性の囲い文字として'と"の混在は文法上許容されるか

Tags: xml

1つのタグや宣言の中で`'シングルクォーテーション'`と`"ダブルクォーテーション"`が混在するXMLは正しい構文でしょうか？

例えば下のXMLは
`<Ex am=" 'シングルクォーテーション' と" ple=' "ダブルクォーテーション" が'>タグの属性の中で混在するが</Ex>`
[W3Cの定義](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/)通りと理解して問題ないでしょうか？

**質問の経緯**

下記のような記述のXMLファイルを使用して読込プログラムの動作チェックを行ったところ、1行目のプロローグでエラーになりました。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='UTF-8'?>
<body>以下略</body>
```

エラーの原因は`version="1.0" encoding='UTF-8'`でクォーテーションの種類が混在していたことです。

お行儀の悪いXML記述と承知しているのですが、W3Cの定義を読んでも**厳密な意味で**間違っているのはXMLなのかプログラムなのか確証が持てませんでした。
XML出力または読込プログラムのどちらかに改修依頼を出す際の判断基準を求めていることが質問の経緯です。

**調べたこと**

日本語翻訳版の[AttValue](http://w4ard.eplusx.net/translation/W3C/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-AttValue)、[2.8 プロローグと文書型宣言](http://w4ard.eplusx.net/translation/W3C/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-prolog-dtd)、[4.3.3 実体で使われる文字エンコーディング](http://w4ard.eplusx.net/translation/W3C/REC-xml-20081126/#charencoding)には、BN記法(バッカス・ナウア記法)？で下記の定義があります。

```
[10] AttValue ::= '"' ( [^<&"] | Reference )* '"'
| "'" ( [^<&'] | Reference )* "'" 

[23] XMLDecl ::= '<?xml' VersionInfo EncodingDecl? SDDecl? S? '?>'
[24] VersionInfo ::= S 'version' Eq ( "'" VersionNum "'" | '"' VersionNum '"' )

[80] EncodingDecl ::= S 'encoding' Eq ( '"' EncName '"' | "'" EncName "'" )
[81] EncName ::= [A-Za-z] ( [A-Za-z0-9._] | '-' )* /* ラテン文字しか含まないエンコーディング名 Encoding name contains only Latin characters */
```

BN記法を良く分かっていませんが、上記の内容から属性に`'`と`"`のどちらも利用できると解釈しています。
ただし混在に関する規定は見つかりませんでした。

Comment: チェックを行ったプログラムの仕様に依るのでは？ こんなサイトのサービスで試してみるとエラーは無いようです。[XML バリデータ](https://www.online-toolz.com/langs/ja/tool-ja-xml-validator.html), [XML Validator Online BETA](http://xmlvalidator.new-studio.org/) まあこれらは緩いのかもしれませんが。そのチェックを行ったプログラムの情報を提示してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: プログラムは依頼により作成したワンオフ製品ですので、仕様はこちらが決める側です。公開はできませんが混在を想定していなかったため関連する仕様はありません。「緩くない規定では混在が許容されますか？」という疑問が、主に解消したい質問の意図です。(もちろん「規約はともかく、この仕様で改修してください」と言えば終わる話ですが、仕様を作るにあたって根拠を知りたいと考えています)

Comment: 構文チェックツールには思い至りませんでした。コメントありがとうございます。

Comment: 例えばW3Cのサイトで提供しているチェックツール [XML Validator](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp) と同等の動作をすることにすれば、根拠に使えるのでは？